# How to handle click event for sap.ui.commons.Area in OpenUI5

Tags: imagemap, sapui5

I am using the ImageMap control to make multiple clickable areas on an image.

```js
var oImage = new sap.ui.commons.Image("i1");
oImage.setSrc("images/FlowersAndWesp.jpg");
oImage.setAlt("alternative image text for i1");
oImage.setUseMap("Map1");
oImage.placeAt("sample1");

var oMap = new sap.ui.commons.ImageMap();
oMap.setName("Map1");
var aArea1 = new sap.ui.commons.Area ("Area1", {shape: "rect", alt: "Bee", href: "http://www.sap.com", coords: "40,20,100,80"});
var aArea2 = new sap.ui.commons.Area ("Area2", {shape: "circle", alt: "Flower", href: "http://www.sap.com", coords: "170,60,30"});
oMap.addArea(aArea1);
oMap.addArea(aArea2);
oMap.placeAt("sample1");
```

When I click on aArea1, aArea2 instead of href click event should be invoke and in that I can write some popup dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sap.ui.commons.Area` doesn't expose a press event itself, but passes it to the parent `ImageMap`.

So if you want to handle the press event of an Area, you'll have to hook your logic up to the `ImageMap` and read the `event` argument to find out which area has been pressed.

Please refer to https://jsbin.com/qujade/edit?html,output for an example of how this works.

Comment: thanks. Can you give a small example may be a bin snippet.

Comment: I've created a little jsbin based on your code and added the link to my answer.